# Disable rich text editor by default

Tags: 6, nodes, wysiwyg

I am using WYSIWYG module with TinyMce as Rich Text Editor.
I need to make the rich text editor disabled only for a particular text area in a create content page, i.e., when I click Enable rich-text link, it must get activated. How can this be done?I am using drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to alter the edit form. This is what I did for Drupal 7.

```php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Disable WYSIWYG just in this field.
  if ($form_id === 'FORM_ID_OF_EDIT_FORM') {
    $form['field_CUSTOM'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#wysiwyg'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

You may want to use `$language->language` instead of `LANGUAGE_NONE`.

Answer (score -2):

I always use [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module with the following steps:

1. Install wysiwyg module
2. Download TinyMce library to libraries (sites/add/libraries) folder
3. Create a new input format, called Wysiwyg (admin/config/content/formats)
4. Set the correct roles to this input format
5. Set this as a full html format (don't convert line breaks to brs etc)
6. Connect wysiwyg profile to this (admin/config/content/wysiwyg)

This solution is for Drupal 7 but you can do it on D6 too with the same steps, just change the administration urls.

Comment: I am using tinymce within WYSIWYG module already

Comment: I'm sorry, I was careless. So you want to disable it only on a specific form element?

Comment: yes, I need to disable it by default only for a text area of one content type only

Comment: Did you try better formats module? Maybe it can help you but I'm not sure